# What does each object do exactly in Quickblox Android Private Chat?

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I've been working on private chat for quite a while now and can't seem to find any answers on what exactly each object does. I have also read the documentation and its simply too brief for a new quickblox user to follow. The main objects I'm referring to are QBPrivateChatManager, QBPrivateChatManagerListener and QBMessageListener.

For example, does each chat need to have its own QBMessageListener or can we have one to handle all chats? Where should we put each of the objects?- should the QBPrivateChatManager be on the chat dialogs page? I think these are questions that should be answered within the XMPP Chat Sample...

It would be really helpful if somebody could give a deeper background as to how everything links together to speed up development while using quickblox. As it stands, the documentation, XMPP Chat Sample and Q-Municate don't explain this very well.

Comment: Can you explain what you tried already?

Comment: So far the app opens onto an activity which retrieves the dialogs currently open for the user. This same activity is where I have defined the QBMessageListener and QBPrivateChatManagerListener objects. In this same activity when the MessageListener processes a message, I update an adapter for that particular chat. When the PrivateChatManager's chatCreated is called, I update the adapter for the page with all the dialogs for the user. To each new private chat created, I add the same global MessageListener. Is this correct or should each chat have its own MessageListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Harmeet, yes, this is correct. in this listener's callbacks you get message and chat, that is enough for correct managing messages in app